# I want to remove messaging app from my aosp ,I removed its entry from all mk files in product package feild

Tags: android, android-source, android-launcher

I removed entry of messaging in front of product packages from mk files of devices and build. still app appears in my phone when I try to flash the images.could anyone please help because for other apps this method worked .Is there any other way or any issue with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to disable it, (and not uninstall), try this from the command prompt.

```bash
adb shell pm disable-user com.android.messaging
```